# How to not sort when connect in Prisma Client

Tags: database, sorting, prisma

I'm using Prisma Client to manage the database. and I found the problem while i'm making front-end.
In Prisma Client, there is a method "connect" and it is really powerful technic to map between tables.
However, for example, I connect three records like A, B, C, by order C, A, B, but when request data to check how it looks, it actually shows like A, B, C.
Is there any way not to sort when using connect?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by default would happen on `id` of A, B, C which is by default and you can configure it using `orderBy` in `include`.

Comment: Is there any way to order by connect time?
I mean, for example, there are models A and B, three records 1, 2, 3 in B and these are connecting to one field of A.
the code like:
`
fieldInA: {
  connect: [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1}],
}
`
and with no orderby, the query response would be 1, 2, 3.
how to query this by the order i insert, with orderby and include?

Comment: That's not possible. The insert order isn't stored anywhere so there's no way for the database to order by a field that doesn't exist.